# DecorView Child FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone explain to me why does the child of DecorView on my layout is a FrameLayout when I have not defined one?

Here is the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_general" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIKUGo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/mainbutton_selector" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewmoto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/motto_buttonpage_hdpi" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: That is the way activities are built in android, besides your content an activity could show other elements, like an action bar. The content of an activity is added to a `FrameLayout` with the `id` `android.R.id.content`.

Comment: @Luksprog Ok i have another example project that the child of DevorView is a LinearLayout ,is something different in this project?

Comment: I don't remember exactly how the `DecorView` is built, but the layout that you set with `setContentView` is added to the `FrameLayout` with the id `android.R.id.content`. Is there any particular reason for your interest on the `DecorView`?

Comment: Thanks for replying I am trying to implement https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu which also has an example, when you run the example  if you check the hiearchyviewer you will see that the decorview has a linearlayout child before the content framelayout.

Comment: I've run those projects, but I don't see any problems. There is the `DecorView` with a `LinearLayout` and a child `FrameLayout`(android.R.id.content) and there is the activity's content view.

Comment: exactly but when I implement this on my project I get the android.R.id.content Framelayout before the linearlayout.

Comment: I doubt that you have a different layout then my tests. You should add a picture with the view hierarchy.

Comment: I maybe have been misunderstood. When I run the example I get exactly what you describe , DecorView->LinearLayout->Framelayout(content).
When I use the library I on my Project I get DecorView->Framelayout(content)->LinearLayout.I am sorry but I cannot add a picture due to stackoverflow Rules.

Comment: Put the image on one of the sites for sharing images(or somewhere else) and post the link here in the comments area. I'll edit your question and add the image. Anyway I've run that example project and I don't see the behavior you talk about.

Comment: the example http://postimage.org/image/xsmgc20c1/ and my project http://postimage.org/image/5tsal6ypd/ implementing the same library

Comment: That is probably happening because you use a `NoTitleBar` theme for your activity and this, apparently, removes the need for the `LinearLayout` between the `DecorView` and the content `FrameLayout`.

Comment: This was the deal indeed , would you like to answer the question so I could mark it as the correct one? Thanks for your help

Comment: Plus this means that if you want to use this library you MUST have a title bar!

Comment: I've posted an answer. If you are going to use that library you should use a title bar(I haven't run on a device with a version that uses the `ActionBar` to see how it behaves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have a `LinearLayout` between the `DecorView` and the `FrameLayout` which holds the content of the `Activity` if you use a normal theme. If you use a `NoTitleBar` type of a theme then there is no need for that extra `LinearLayout` so it's removed leaving the content `FrameLayout` as the child of the `DecorView`.