# DecorView child framelayout is different at devices

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I use the library similar in `github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu`

And it worked very well in `HTC device(ICS)` and `Nexus 7(ICS)`, and other `Gingerbread` device.

But some devices like `Motorola atrix` and another `HTC` device.

So I checked the code.

```
View view  = act.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Utils.Log("<SlideMenu> : VIEW : "+view);        
ViewParent viewParent = view.getParent();
Utils.Log("<SlideMenu> : VIEW : "+viewParent);  
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) viewParent;
Utils.Log("<SlideMenu> : VIEW : "+linearLayout);
content = linearLayout;
```

In here, first thing returns `FrameLayout` on all of devices.

But second thing returns `LinearLayout` on `ICS` device and other `HTC 2.3` device, and some devices return `DecorView`.

I refer this post : [DecorView Child FrameLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650847/decorview-child-framelayout)

They said it is problem that I use `NoTitleBar`, so I show title bar but it doesn't work.

Also, Even though I added `NoTitleBar` attribute, some devices do work very well.

It's really frustrating since devices have different result. Does anyone know about it?

Please Help :D Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe we can be certain of a few things regarding PhoneWindow$DecorView (or at least as certain as one developing for android can be).

Firstly, DecorView extends FrameLayout and, therefore, we can be confident in casting it to parent class ViewGroup. That said, secondly, we can also be confident that the DecorView contains parent class View(s) (otherwise it would be a rather boring ViewGroup wouldn't it).

This leads me to the conclusion that this problem should be attacked from the top down rather than bottom up as the library code in question is attempting.

For example something like this:

```
ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
View oldScreen = decorView.getChildAt(0);
decorView.removeViewAt(0);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
SlidingPanel slidingPanel = (SlidingPanel) inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_slider, null);
((ViewGroup) slidingPanel.findViewById(R.id.anterior)).addView(oldScreen);
decorView.addView(slidingPanel, 0);
```

I have recently implemented a similar rudimentary SlidingPanel widget and make use of it as per above. You can find it and further example usage here https://github.com/mubeta06/android/tree/master/SlidingFrame.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have no chance to try this code, but I solve this problem different way. Anyway, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Android SDK documentation that specifies the layout type of `android.R.id.content`, let alone its parent. This can vary, either by Android OS release, device manufacturer alterations, or modded ROM changes. Most SDK developers should not even be *touching* the parent of `android.R.id.content`; none should be assuming anything specific about it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu/commit/9b9ae22c8e463559324e377f6e89a430dd4fd7ca hopefully fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for comment, But I already tried it. And it still can't solve problem in Motorola Atrix. If I use this I can avoid crash, but slide menu cover original view when I use show() method. (But hide() method works very well. )

Answer (score 0):

Check this link I did for [LibSlideMenu](https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu/issues/12):

```
private static ViewGroup parent;
```

Converted all `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` to

```
LayoutParams  parent = (ViewGroup) act.getWindow().getDecorView();
```